# What causes ComboBox to show `System.Data.DataRowView`

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, combobox

OK, so this one is a bit odd.

I have a pretty straightforward `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("Equals", "==");
dt.Rows.Add("Is Less Than", "<");
dt.Rows.Add("Is Less Than Or Equal To", "<=");
dt.Rows.Add("Is Greater Than", ">");
dt.Rows.Add("Is Greater Than Or Equal To", ">=");
```

Now, if I attach this `DataTable` to a brand new `ComboBox`, everything works as it should.

```
 comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

This control displays `Equals`, `Is Less Than`, etc.

In my form, however, I have another `ComboBox` that is dynamically created, given a dynamic name based on which row in a `TableLayoutPanel` it is in, etc. 
When I use the *exact same code* for it, it displays `System.Data.DataRowView` for each dropdown selection:

[image: Screenshot]

So, rather than me going through each line of code one by one and trying to reverse engineer this, **can someone tell me what would cause this to happen?** Is there some predictable and repeatable way to cause this behaviour? I've tried all of the following to *reverse* it but nothing works:

```
dtecComboAction.DataSource = null;
dtecComboAction.DataBindings.Clear();
dtecComboAction.Items.Clear();
dtecComboAction.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

I'm sure I'm doing something obvious somewhere else in my code but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Typically the only way you would get this is **not** setting the `DataSource` as well as the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. When you don't the mapping doesn't know where to look, all it knows is the backing source is a `DataRowView`. Can you show the code that create's these dynamic controls?

Comment: Typically not setting the Display and Value members results in this behavior.

Comment: I just checked to see if something else was overriding it but nothing there. Also in code I am using `SelectedValue` and it's returning the `Value` column, so seems like that is working.

Comment: @tmwoods show your code, if we can't see what you are doing, we are of no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unexpected behavior described in the question is determined by a custom drawing of the OwnerDrawn ComboBox (a Custom Control derived from ComboBox).

When the DataSource of a ListControl is a complex object - as in this case, a [DataTable.DefaultView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.defaultview) (a [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview)) - each Item in the list is a complex object itself, a [`DataRowView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview) here.

For this reason, when drawing the Items of an OwnerDrawn ListControl (overriding the `OnDrawItem` method), the Item's text, as displayed in the Control's visible area, should be fetched using the ListControl's [GetItemText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext) method.

This method fetches an Item's text (using the internal DataManager if a DataSource has been defined, or the TypeDescriptor if not), no matter what the Item's Type is:

> If the DisplayMember property is not specified, the value returned by
> GetItemText(Object) is the value of the item's ToString method.
> Otherwise, the method returns the string value of the member specified
> in the DisplayMember property for the object specified in the item
> parameter.

[.Net Source code of ListControl.GetItemText()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,555)

A classic mistake when drawing an Item's text it to convert to string the Item's object.
This can work if the Item's text is a simple string, not if it's a complex object. In this case **`[ComplexObject].ToString()`** returns the object's data type (`System.Data.DataRowView`, in this case).

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // (...)
    e.DrawBackground();
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Items[e.Index].ToString()), Font, brush, e.Bounds);
    }
    // (...)
}
```

<sup>Simplified sample code, do not use :)</sup>

Using **`GetItemText()`**, the property value of `DisplayMember` is returned as a string. Since `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";`, it will return the content of the DataTable's `Display` Column.

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // (...)
    e.DrawBackground();
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, brush, e.Bounds);
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote this. This fixed my problem.