# WinForms Custom ComboBox does not display names of List<> items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to create a custom ComboBox in c# Winforms for using with custom Highlight color.
Found some examples from the internet and modified a little to keep my codes clean.But there is something wrong that i can not fix so i need your help.

here my custom ComboBox class:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TesTApp
{
    class ThemedComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        protected Color _HighLightColor;       
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("High Light Color for selection"),
        System.ComponentModel.Category("HighLight"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Gray")]
        public Color HighlightColor
        {
            get { return _HighLightColor; }
            set
            {
                _HighLightColor = value;
                Invalidate();
                Update();
            }
        }

        public ThemedComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            HighlightColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 167, 36);
            this.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBox_DrawItem);            
        }
        void ComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index < 0)
                return;

            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(HighlightColor),
                                         e.Bounds);
            else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor),
                                         e.Bounds);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                                  new SolidBrush(ForeColor),
                                  new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
    }
}
```

When i call the method for fill the ComboBox with List , DropDown does not display the names of items.

At first i created a class to fill the data

```
  public class testItems
    {
        public string itemName { get; set; }
        public int itemValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And then i am calling the method that fills the ComboBox :

```
int maxItem = 5;
private void TestComboBox1()
{
   List<testItems> _list = new List<testItems>();
   for (int i = 0; i < maxItem; i++)
   {
     _list.Add(new testItems
      {
        itemName = "Item no: " + i.ToString(),
        itemValue = i
       });
   }
   themedComboBox1.DataSource = _list;
   themedComboBox1.DisplayMember = "itemName";
   themedComboBox1.ValueMember = "itemValue";
}
```

With this method , ComboBox DropDown does not display the name(DisplayMember) of items.

[image: Result is like in this picture:]

Then i have tried to fill ComboBox with a string array.With string array ComboBox displays the items but with this way i can not give values to items.

Here my method for fill the ComboBox with string array:

```
 int maxItem = 5;
 private void TestComboBox2()
 {
   string[] items = new string[maxItem];
   for (int i = 0; i < maxItem; i++)
   {
      items[i] = "Item No : " + i;
   }
   themedComboBox2.DataSource = items;
 }
```

[image: Result of filling the ComboBox with string array]

All i want to have a custom ComboBox with custom Highlight color.Where am i doing wrong? Can you please help me to correct this?

Comment: [What causes ComboBox to show `System.Data.DataRowView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58294994/7444103). -- You can also cast the current `Item` to the underlying object type. BTW, set `DisplayMember` **before** you set the `DataSource`.

Comment: Same here: [ListBox items do not show in OwnerDrawFixed Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832936/7444103), with a more complete code.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your comment but in this case setting DisplayMember before than the DataSource did not made any difference.

Comment: Setting the `DisplayMember` property before the `DataSource` property is not related to your current problem, it's something else (which you'll need to consider if the list count grows. Not only in relation to the ComboBox control). What is related to your *problem* is in the two links I posted. Give it a look, if you actually want to use `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properly (so you don't need to cast all the time to extract a Value from the underlying object) and to understand where the problem lies.

Comment: @Jimi a code from your first comment works also:`e.Graphics.DrawString(this.GetItemText(this.Items[e.Index]), this.Font, brush, e.Bounds);`

Comment: Yes, that's one of the pieces you need. Your ComboBox needs to work with all kind of data sources. What if you want to use a DataTable or a Dictionary as the DataSource? Do you override `ToString()` of a `DataRowView` object? Or the `KeyValuePair` of a Dictionary? About the `DisplayMember`: when you set this property, the (any) Control needs to rebind the DataSource if one is already set, with the result of querying the data source twice. Annoying if your data source comes from the Web or a remote Data Server. If you have a local list of 5 elements you won't notice it.

Comment: @Jimi i am always prefer the `KeyValuePair` of a Dictionary. Because of override is like doing same job twice to me. Actually i will use this ComboBox with EntityFramework tables. And i think overriding would not be the best solution.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Setup your ComboBox (or ListBox or whatever) properly and you won't have to change a single line of code if/when the DataSource type changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you see "TestTApp.testItems" are actually generated in the virtual method `Object.ToString()`. If your sole issue is replacing these values, you can override that ToString method for your `testItems` class (which, by the way, I'd recommend naming `TestItem`)

See this:

```
public class testItems
{
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int itemValue { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return itemName;
    }
}
```

Working with lists and Combo boxes (not limited to combo boxes) is fairly simple, you don't have to worry about row numbers and column names as you have to do with general data sources. In fact, you don't even need to set the `DisplayMember` and `DataMember`.

Just notice that when working with this kind of approach, you work with values of type `testItems`, and not actually the type which you desired `ValueMember` to hold. For instance, calling `themedComboBox1.SelectedValue` returns an `testItems` object (and not an `int`).